# Multi-language variable for Laravel Nova Admin panel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I want to add multiple languages ​​for the panel. For example, I want to change sources, logout, copyright and similar fields.
How can I do it. Are there any Laravel nova packages?

Answer (score 0):

copy from
nova/resources/views
to
resources/views/vendor/nova